# Should a tag be created for questions related to direct payments from a government for compensation, salary, wages, etc.?

Tags: discussion, tags

Each of these questions, in some way, relates to payments made by a government to individuals elected or appointed to, or employed by, a government, as compensation in terms of salary, wages, etc.

Given there are at least 0 <strike>22</strike> questions, should a tag be created for this type of question? And, if so, what should placed in the tag excerpt?

- <strike>[Where can I see the total compensation (by year?) of each of the employees of the UN?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/where-can-i-see-the-total-compensation-by-year-of-each-of-the-employees-of-th)</strike>
- [Why do people at the top of a bureaucracy/government have to get paid the most?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63547/why-do-people-at-the-top-of-a-bureaucracy-government-have-to-get-paid-the-most)
- [What are the reasons for not calculating government officials' wages in terms of minimal wage?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33821/what-are-the-reasons-for-not-calculating-government-officials-wages-in-terms-of)
- [Do high-level US government officials who are fired receive any compensation?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/29810/do-high-level-us-government-officials-who-are-fired-receive-any-compensation)
- [Why are some government services/programs closed from the federal government shutdown, while others aren't?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/why-are-some-government-services-programs-closed-from-the-federal-government-shu)
- [Why do politicians make so much money? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13837/why-do-politicians-make-so-much-money)
- [Do E.U. employees pay tax on their salaries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/715/do-e-u-employees-pay-tax-on-their-salaries/716)
- [Does President Trump's sister still draw a federal salary?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35120/does-president-trumps-sister-still-draw-a-federal-salary)
- [Do POWs typically get paid for their prison time?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/do-pows-typically-get-paid-for-their-prison-time)
- [Why don't politicians decide to pass laws that make themselves really rich?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/why-dont-politicians-decide-to-pass-laws-that-make-themselves-really-rich)
- [US Presidential salary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/us-presidential-salary)
- [Why do US politicians spend so much on campaigns when the salary is not high enough to justify the expenditure?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/why-do-us-politicians-spend-so-much-on-campaigns-when-the-salary-is-not-high-eno)
- [Are US politicians still paid a salary when they cause a government shutdown? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/are-us-politicians-still-paid-a-salary-when-they-cause-a-government-shutdown)
- [Have the salaries or benefits of members of the Constitutional Court ever been decreased in an European country?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66066/have-the-salaries-or-benefits-of-members-of-the-constitutional-court-ever-been-d)
- [Does the US 2013 sequester affect politicians own salaries and benefits?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/does-the-us-2013-sequester-affect-politicians-own-salaries-and-benefits)
- [How does “politician” work as a job/career?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41281/how-does-politician-work-as-a-job-career)
- [What sort of evidence exists that higher salaries for political offices attract better candidates?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/what-sort-of-evidence-exists-that-higher-salaries-for-political-offices-attract)
- [How wealthy are state legislators in Texas?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/how-wealthy-are-state-legislators-in-texas)
- [Are there any proposed systems of running the government like a corporation?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/316/are-there-any-proposed-systems-of-running-the-government-like-a-corporation)
- [Why are elected representatives paid so much less than corporate top managers? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19144/why-are-elected-representatives-paid-so-much-less-than-corporate-top-managers)
- [In China, can competent government officials get rich legitimately? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/in-china-can-competent-government-officials-get-rich-legitimately)
- [In the news, it says “essential” government employees would be required to work without pay. How?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37447/in-the-news-it-says-essential-government-employees-would-be-required-to-work)

Comment: Does the existing [income] tag work? Or is that not a good fit because it's also used for general political questions about salaries for non-government employees?

Comment: @JJJ - I am not adamantly opposed to using [income], however, like [basic-income] and [social security], there seems to be more politics to it than mere income.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure either. For example, it's often okay to mix tags to mean something specific, like mixing [income] and [tax] to ask about income tax (rather than a new [income-tax]). On the other hand, we do have [presidential-election] because it's such a popular combo. If there are many questions about it then I think it help to have a dedicated tag so the questions can be found more easily and to leave room for other tags on those questions. Feel free to self-answer if you have a good idea about phrasing such a combined tag, maybe [government-salaries] and [public-salaries] as a synonym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to make a dedicated tag for this. I'm not sure if there's one description that captures it all because you probably want to capture government salaries as well as compensation from other publicly funded institutions.

I'd suggest [public-sector-compensation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-sector-compensation) as the main tag with the following synonyms:

- [public-sector-salaries](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-sector-salaries)
- [government-salaries](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government-salaries)

Comment: I like it. When adding tags to a question, typing any of "gov", "sal" or "comp" should should make the tag or synonym visible. However, with "sal" both "salaries" tags would show, if I understand correctly how it works. I would opt for using the [government-salaries] as a lone synonym rather than [public-sector-salaries]. Presenting two tag synonyms that mean the same thing could be confusing.

Comment: @RickSmith Even with these overlapping tags, only the main tag shows up with the synonym(s) below in the tag description. For example, when you type `stoc`, the [money-supply] tag shows up [like this](https://i.imgur.com/axeyW43.png).

Comment: These synonyms are now active.